# Why am I still getting the error: "CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available" in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, pycrypto, pyopenssl

I am trying to make an API call through Python to Google's DFA and am using their suggested code. However, it is still not saying the credentials object is defined and throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1502, in __init__
    _RequireCryptoOrDie()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1456, in _RequireCryptoOrDie
    raise CryptoUnavailableError('No crypto library available')
CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available
```

I have installed the pyOpenSSL library, and pycrypto library with the VCForPython compiler. I have also managed to edit all 3 app.yaml files in the LiClipse client to append:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```

onto it.

This is what my code looks like so far with arbitrary credentials:

```
import json    
import sys    
import apiclient    
from oauth2client import crypt    
import ssl    
import urllib2    
from OpenSSL import crypto    


HAS_OPENSSL = False    
HAS_CRYPTO = False    
try:    
  from oauth2client import crypt    
  HAS_CRYPTO = True    
  if crypt.OpenSSLVerifier is not None:    
    HAS_OPENSSL = True    
except ImportError:    
  pass


from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials    

client_email = 'example.apps.googleusercontent.com'    

with open("C:\My Project-1234.p12") as f:    
        private_key = f.read()     


credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting')    

from httplib2 import Http
```

I realize there is probably some excess in the beginning. I have not been able to get past this step.

I feel like I have tried everything and am still getting thrown the 'no crypto library' error.

Can anyone help? THANK YOU!

PS - I am using Windows 7 and Python 2.7 and LiClipse.

Comment: Have you confirmed you can actually import pyopenssl or pycrypto from your script? Try importing those before *oauth2client* to verify.

Comment: pyopenssl seems to import. i have not been able to get pycrypto installed despite downloading the compiler and windows sdk. I now have the code running until the last line here: "service = build('dfareporting', 'v2.1', http=http_auth)" where i am actually attempting a call. I am now getting the error: OpenSSL.crypto.Error: []. So, still related to the cryptos it seems.

Comment: I also have this problem in Windows 10 (upgraded from Win 7), Python Tools for Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2013 and Python 3.4 virtual env. Strangest thing: it works with a venv in an Eclipse project. I manually compared site-packages in both venv's but can't see any difference. My Python skills not good enough to figure out why it works in one venv and not the other

Answer (score 0):

The above method was to make an API call as a 'service' Google account. I retried as an 'installed application' account with new credentials and a different way to make the API call which did not require any crypto type libraries.